# Quick Check for CoffeeScript

Tags: haskell, coffeescript, quickcheck

Does it exist? I can't find it and it isn't listed on wikipedia. (which means it doesn't exist :) )

I know node.js has it. Not sure if writing my node app in coffeescript and applying quick check would work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_check

Any clues?

Comment: Can you just use QC.js ?

Comment: CoffeeScript is just a *syntax* layer on Javascript -- anything that works with Javascript should work with CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any QuickCheck library written *particularly* in or for CoffeeScript, but googling pulls up [qc.js](https://bitbucket.org/darrint/qc.js/src). Here's a snippet from demo.js in that repository:

```
declare("reverse", [arbWholeNumList, arbWholeNumList],
        function(c, x, y) {
            var z = x.concat(y);
            x.reverse();
            y.reverse();
            z.reverse();
            c.assert(z.toString() == y.concat(x).toString());
        });
```

Now I'm no CoffeeScript expert, but I ran this through http://js2coffee.org. If you can manage to import qc.js, then using it from CoffeeScript would look something like this:

```
declare "reverse", [ arbWholeNumList, arbWholeNumList ], (c, x, y) ->
  z = x.concat(y)
  x.reverse()
  y.reverse()
  z.reverse()
  c.assert z.toString() is y.concat(x).toString()
```